# I am trying to extract phone numbers using re.findall( ).But it shows TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Tags: python, python-re

1. Problem Statement

> The need to easily verify phone numbers in any relevant scenario.

Consider the following Phone numbers:

```
444-122-1234
123-122-78999
111-123-23
67-7890-2019
```

The general format of a phone number is as follows:

```
Starts with 3 digits and ‘-‘ sign
3 middle digits and ‘-‘ sign
4 digits in the end
```

My Code

```
import re
l1=[444-122-1234,123-122-78999,111-123-23,67-7890-2019]
k=[]
for i in l1:
    str1=re.findall(r'\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}',i)
    print(str1)
```

[image]

Comment: i can see you have ```{3}```, and all. Are you trying to format strings'

Comment: No I am trying to figure out which of the elements of the list conform to the given patterns.

Comment: None of the list elements match your actual regex pattern.  Double check your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With List Comprehension:

```
 import re
 l1= ['444-122-1234', '123-122-78999', '111-123-23', '67-7890-2019']
    
 str1 = [re.findall(r'\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}', i) for i in l1 if re.findall(r'\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}', i) ]
 print(str1)
```

Output:

```
Out[18]: [['44-122-1234'], ['23-122-7899']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put each of the phone numbers in the `l1` list inside quotations. Now they are just integers with some minus calculations.